# Создание Servlet'а

Tags: java, servlet

Приветствую. Подскажите, почему второй вариант кода не принимает компилятор?
В чем разница?

Первый вариант:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ResourceServlet(resourceServer)), ResourceServlet.PAGE_URL);
```

Второй вариант:

```
 Server server = new Server(8080);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

    ResourceServlet rs = new ResourceServlet(resourceServer);

    testResource.setAge(rs.getResourceServerMBean().getAge());
    testResource.setName(rs.getResourceServerMBean().getName());

    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(rs, ResourceServlet.PAGE_URL);
```

Во втором варианте ругается на конструктор Сервлетхолдера и пишет: Cannot resolve constructor 'ServletHolder(servlets.ResourceServlet,java.lang.String)'ResourceServlet extends HttpServlet

Comment: Ошибка `Cannot resolve constructor` означает, что вы пытаетесь создать экземляр класса используя несуществующий конструктор.

Comment: потеряли скобку после `rs`

Comment: Спасибо) Заплутал в 2 соснах) Дело в скобке)